# ambiguous tags: friend / friends / friendship

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

[friend](/questions/tagged/friend) (356 questions), [friends](/questions/tagged/friends) (194 questions) and [friendship](/questions/tagged/friendship) (43 questions) are ambiguous.  Sometimes they refer to `friend` classes/functions as in C++, sometimes to social networking "friends", and sometimes to other things entirely.

Questions are often paired with [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook), [facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api) or [facebook-fql](/questions/tagged/facebook-fql), implying it's referring to social networking friends, or with [private](/questions/tagged/private), [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [namespaces](/questions/tagged/namespaces), implying it's referring to `friend` classes/functions.

[friend-function](/questions/tagged/friend-function) and [friend-class](/questions/tagged/friend-class) are the only tags that I see as possibilities to retag some of these as.  However, I think the distinction between these tags is not useful, but I don't have an idea for a single unambiguous tag name for this concept.  I have no idea on how to retag the other questions.

How should these questions be retagged?

Comment: Do they even need to be retagged?  The combination of [friend+facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+friend) is unambiguous, as is [friend+class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend+class) and [friend+function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend+function).